# JPA/EclipseLink Concurrency issue with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, concurrency, eclipselink

I am running into concurrency problem with my application which uses JPA/EclipseLink and MySQL as a database. I need an advice here.
I have a client which generates blocks of string in a file. Each block may contain from few lines up to 100 or 200 lines. Right after generating the data, client starts to send set of blocks to the server where each block is parsed accordingly and stored in the db. The server uses JPA/EclipseLink to communicate with MySQL.
When the client sends set of blocks in a synchronous way (through REST), everything works as expected in terms of parsing the data and storing them in the db. However, when the client sends the data in parallel (15 concurrent threads in my case), some data(several lines) is just skipped during storing in the db only for the first time. When the same data is sent in parallel again(second time, third time, etc..), it just works as expected (no lines are skipped during storing them).
For just testing purposes in the case of parallel sending, I stored all the lines in a concurrent map. I did not see any skipped lines in the map, so it is a purely JPA and/or MySQL issue. I tried to use Optimistic/Pessimistic locks with JPA, but they did not help.
Can you please advise me, what is going on if someone got into this kind of situation?

Here are my three relevant entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECT")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Project.findByKey", query = "SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.key = :P_KEY",
                hints = {
                        @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.QUERY_RESULTS_CACHE, value = HintValues.TRUE),
                        @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.QUERY_RESULTS_CACHE_SIZE, value = "1000"),
                        @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.QUERY_RESULTS_CACHE_IGNORE_NULL, value = HintValues.TRUE),
                        @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.BIND_PARAMETERS, value = HintValues.TRUE)
                }
        )
})
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType
@CascadeOnDelete
@OptimisticLocking
public class Project implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name = "p-table-gen", table = "SEQ", pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName = "SEQ_COUNT", pkColumnValue = "PROJECT_SEQ", allocationSize = 50)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "p-table-gen")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "DURATION")
    private Long duration;

    @Column(name = "PROGRAM")
    private String program;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides(
        {
            @AttributeOverride(name = "parentHash", column = @Column(name = "PARENT_CMD_HASH")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "hash", column = @Column(name = "CMD_HASH")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "pathHash", column = @Column(name = "PATH_HASH"))
        }
    )
    ProjectKey key = new ProjectKey();

    @BatchFetch(BatchFetchType.EXISTS)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true )
    @XmlTransient
    @CascadeOnDelete
    private List<Task> tasks = new Vector<Task>();

    @BatchFetch(BatchFetchType.EXISTS)
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true )
    @XmlTransient
    @CascadeOnDelete
    private Environment environment;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    private Long version;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "TASK")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Task.findTaskByBuildAndPathName",
                query = "SELECT t FROM Task t WHERE t.operation = 'W' AND t.key.pathName = :PATH_NAME ORDER BY t.startTime",
                hints = {
                        @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.BIND_PARAMETERS, value = HintValues.TRUE)
                }
        )
})
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType
@CascadeOnDelete
@OptimisticLocking
public class Task implements Serializable, Constants {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name = "t-table-gen", table = "SEQ", pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName = "SEQ_COUNT", pkColumnValue = "TASK_SEQ", allocationSize = 200)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "t-table-gen")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "HASH")
    private String hash;

    @Column(name = "OPERATION")
    private String operation;

    @Column(name = "PROCESS_ID")
    private BigInteger processId;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(name = "nanoseconds", column = @Column(name = "START_TIME"))
    private Moment startTime;

    @Column(name = "THREAD_ID")
    private BigInteger threadId;

    @Column(name = "THROUGHPUT")
    private Float throughput;

    @Column(name = "PROCESSED_BYTES")
    private Float processedBytes;

    @BatchFetch(BatchFetchType.JOIN)
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PATH_STATE_ID", insertable = false, updatable = true)
    @CascadeOnDelete
    private TaskKey key;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_ID")
    @XmlTransient
    @CascadeOnDelete
    private Project project;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    private Long version;
}



@Entity
@Index(name="IDX_TS_SIZE_TIME_INDEX", columnNames={"SIZE","TIME"})
@Table(name = "TASK_STATE")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "TaskState.findByKey", query = "SELECT ts FROM TaskState ts WHERE ts.key = :TS_KEY",
                hints = {
                        @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.QUERY_RESULTS_CACHE, value = HintValues.TRUE),
                        @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.QUERY_RESULTS_CACHE_SIZE, value = "2000"),
                        @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.QUERY_RESULTS_CACHE_IGNORE_NULL, value="true"),
                        @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.BIND_PARAMETERS, value = HintValues.TRUE)
                }
        )
})
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType
public class TaskState implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name = "ts-table-gen", table = "SEQ", pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName = "SEQ_COUNT", pkColumnValue = "TASK_STATE_SEQ", allocationSize = 50)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "ts-table-gen")
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private byte[] artifact;

    @Column(name = "MODE")
    private String mode;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "nanoseconds", column = @Column(name = "TIME")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "size", column = @Column(name = "SIZE")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "pathName", column = @Column(name = "NAME")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "fileHash", column = @Column(name = "HASH"))
    })
    TaskStateKey key = new TaskStateKey();

    @BatchFetch(BatchFetchType.EXISTS)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "taskState", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @XmlTransient
    @CascadeOnDelete
    private List<Task> tasks = new Vector<Task>();
}
```

**Update**
Now I guess I found the root problem but I haven't found the solution yet.
Initially, I am creating a project on database, then trying find relevant taskStates. Initially there are no taskStates so I am creating one by one. So here is consequence of the operations regarding to taskState:
1. Trying to find taskState by a key, if there is one, returning it, otherwise
2. Persisting/inserting new taskState (When there are multiple threads trying to do insert operation, I am receiving duplicate entry errors, therefore I am just retrying the insert operation until I am successful.) and returning newly created pathState.

I see skipped lines whenever I receive duplicate entry errors on current insert operation of pathState even in second or third time I am succeeding to persist a pathState. I can enabled SERIALIZABLE isolation level on database, but this will be inefficient which I cannot afford in my case, and I doubt that SERIALIZABLE isolation would solve my problem.

Comment: It would help is you showed us what your Entity looks like. Do you have a @Version field?

Comment: Can you define what exactly is 'skipped'?  What is one block/line?  How are you sending it, and what does your log show for the skipped data?  Does the data duplicate or repeat entities?

Comment: As I said, the client is sending set of blocks to the server and each block contains several lines of strings. During saving them on database, some lines were not saved in some blocks. Consider each line as a long string which may contain few hundred characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my above problem. I made a slight change to a TASK_STATE ORM class. Specifically, I removed tasks list from the class and it started working as expected. It seems this relation was leading to skip few lines in a heavily concurrent threads.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ID generation strategy of TaskState from TABLE to IDENTITY; this will allow MySQL to set on its own the IDs of inserted rows.

Comment: No it didn't help. Actually I was using AUTO_INCREMENT in the table.

Comment: `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "p-table-gen")` causes JPA to assign a value to `id` property, skipping the AUTO_INCREMENT behavior from MySQL.